# Conversion differences between C# and F# using same library

Tags: .net, f#, clr

I'm sure that this has something to do with the internals of what is going on here.  Hopefully someone can clarify.

I am accessing a library that is C# friendly.

I have one particular object that acts as an array (it is a user defined type from the lib).  Within C# I can call.

`myObject[0] = 1`

And I have no errors in doing so.

If I try to perform the following in F# I get an error - `The expression was expected to have type float32 but instead has type int.`

`myObject.[0] <- 1`

This works.

`myObject.[0] <- float32 1`

So the question is, why is it that in C# this type conversion is happening automatically and in F# it is not?  Is there anything that I can do in F# to clean something like this up?

Comment: More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The F# type checking mechanism is more strict than the type checking in C# in a number of ways. One aspect of this is that F# does not do any implicit conversions behind the scenes and so you have to use the right numeric literals (like `1.0f`) or explicit conversion functions (like `float32`).

Why is the language designed in this way? One reason is that it makes type inference simpler and more predictable. For example:

```
let data = [| 0; 1; 2 |]

let writeData n = 
  data.[0] <- n
```

Here, the F# compiler knows that `data` is of type `int[]` (because it is initialized to an array containing integers). It also knows that `writeData` is a function `int -> unit` because the array contains integers and so `n` has to be an integer too.

If the compiler did implicit conversions, there would be a lot of uncertainties:

- `data` could be, for example, `float[]` or `float32[]` because you could implicitly convert the integers to other numeric types
- `dwriteData` could take any numeric type that is convertible to `int` (such as `int16`, `sbyte` etc.)

This would make the type information a lot more complicated and you'd probably have to specify types explicitly more often. For this reason, F# chooses a tradeoff - you have to write conversions explicitly, but then you do not need to use type annotations as often.